# Prevent Firefox from scrolling while I type in the search within page bar?

Tags: firefox

When I use ⌘ + F to search the current page in Firefox and I begin typing, Firefox immediately starts scrolling to the next match on the page.

[image: video showing firefox scrolling when I type in the page search bar]

I don't always want this behavior, often times I simply want to see if the word I'm interested in appears *in the current view*, so I will search with *Highlight All* enabled, then manually scroll back to the place I started to see if anything is highlighted.

I tried browsing about:config with a search for the word `search` but none of the settings there seem to match what I want.

[image: the about:search page filtered down to "search"]

How do I turn off this auto-scroll behavior of Firefox?